# javascript: mouseover thumbnail, larger image not working after 8th table entry

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been tasked to expand a portfolio page however when I copy and paste the same code to create/duplicate more tables on the page the javascript mouseover thumbnail no longer works beyond the 8th entry. (See Design Project 9 in link). However, I can place the same images and thumbnails in the 8th entry and it works perfectly.

Here is the link: http://petrodesignbuild.com/portfoliotest0811.php

HTML Code:

```html
`<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" width="764" align="center" class="gallery">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top">
              <p><span class="inttxt"><b>Design Project 9</b></span><br /> Place cursor over photo to view larger</p>
            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="350" align="left" valign="top" style="border-right:solid 1px #d6d6d6 ">
              <div id="gallery">
                <h3>Before </h3><br />
                <img src="images/thumbs/arlington_before1_thumb.jpg" alt="" width="94" height="61" onmouseover="swap('arlington_before1', 'large9')" /><img src="images/thumbs/arlington_before2_thumb.jpg"
                  alt="" width="94" height="61" onmouseover="swap('arlington_before2.jpg', 'large9')" /><img src="images/thumbs/arlington_before3_thumb.jpg" alt=""
                  width="94" height="61" onmouseover="swap('arlington_before3.jpg', 'large9')" /><br />
                <h3>After</h3><br />
                <img src="images/thumbs/arlington_after1_thumb.jpg" alt="" width="94" height="61" onmouseover="swap('arlington_after1.jpg', 'large9')" /><img src="images/thumbs/arlington_after2_thumb.jpg"
                  alt="" width="94" height="61" onmouseover="swap('arlington_after2.jpg', 'large9')" /><img src="images/thumbs/arlington_after3_thumb.jpg" alt=""
                  width="94" height="61" onmouseover="swap('arlington_after3.jpg', 'large9')" /></p>
                <p>A small backyard with a <em>staircase
                          to nowhere</em> was transformed into a true outdoor room with the use of creative masonry and stonework design; This &ldquo;room&rdquo; now has water features including a fountain and a spa, and an outdoor fireplace that all
                  merge seamlessly with the use of elegant curves.
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="md-services.php"> Custom Stone &amp; Masonry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="wpps-services.php">Pools, Spas &amp;  Garden
                              Ponds
                            </a></li>
                    <li><a href="ld-services.php">Lighting Design</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td width="397" align="left" valign="top" style="padding:32px 0px 0px 10px;"><img src="images/gallery/arlington_after1.jpg" name="large9" width="363" height="363" id="large2" /> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <p align="right" style="padding-right: 20px"> <a href="#top">back to top</a> </p>
        <center>
          <hr noshade="noshade" class="b">
        </center>`
```

Javascript:

```js
function swap(xSrc,xName) {
 var image = "images/gallery/" + xSrc.toString();
 document.getElementById(xName).src = image;
 document.getElementById('gallerytxt').innerHTML = xName;
 
 return false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always check your browser's console ;)

#### Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Please ***remove or change*** the following code. Note, that an ID can only be set once and not multiple times:    `document.getElementById('gallerytxt').innerHTML = xName`

#### Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

You made a fault here. I guess you forgot renaming the id

`<img src="images/gallery/arlington_after1.jpg" name="large9" width="363" height="363" id="large2">`

Change the `id="large2"` to `id="large9"` instead and the code will work properly.